# How to find and replace subexpression of AST in Julia

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

Suppose I have an expression like `:(Main.i / (0.5 * Main.i * sin(Main.i))`.

I would like to replace each occurence of `Main.i` into some other symbol. Is there an idiomatic way to do this in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Main.i` is not a symbol but an expression, which you can check by doing `dump(:(Main.i))`.

Here is a quick writeup what I think might match your needs:

```
function expr_replace(expr, old, new)
    expr == old && return new
    if expr isa Expr
        expr = deepcopy(expr) # to avoid mutation of source
        for i in eachindex(expr.args)
            expr.args[i] = expr_replace(expr.args[i], old, new)
        end
    end
    expr
end
```

Does it work for you?

EDIT: Here is a version that does a minimal safe use of `deepcopy`:

```
function expr_replace(expr, old, new)
    function f(expr)
        expr == old && return deepcopy(new)
        if expr isa Expr
            for i in eachindex(expr.args)
                expr.args[i] = f(expr.args[i])
            end
        end
        expr
    end

    f(deepcopy(expr))
end
```

In general I guess this will not matter that much as you probably will not want to pass 100 lines of code through this function.

Comment: Won't this do a lot of unnecessary `deepcopy`s?

Comment: Yest - I treated it rather as a way to show what is going on. I will write a second version that avoids using `deepcopy` so much.